# Is it possible to recompile a Windows driver for Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, drivers, compatibility

My printer (Lexmark X9350) doesn't have a Linux driver but I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I installed Windows XP on an old hard drive, but I'd rather be able to print from Linux than have to turn off the computer and switch the hard drive and boot a clunky old OS just to print something.  Question says it all - Is there any way to install the Windows driver on Linux?

Comment: You have constrained the possible help here to a single option of driver recompilation, which is an unlikely solution.  Are you interested in alternative solutions?  If so, [edit] your question and include the printer make and model and the distribution of Linux you are using, and your PC details, as other solutions might be possible.

Comment: "Is there any way to install the Windows driver on Linux?" - No;  Windows drivers call Windows functions.  These don't exist on Linux.

Comment: Question has been edited

Comment: @Ramhound - I understand Windows has different functions, but is there a way to install those functions on Linux?  Wine does an okay job of it for programs, but it doesn't work for drivers, but is it possible for something like that to exist?

Comment: Linux does have some generic printer drivers that might work. I would especially recommend updating to ubuntu 16.04 to have the best possibility of ubuntu being able to use your printer. Have you tried hooking it up to your ubuntu machine and attempting to print something?

Comment: Yes I tried a bunch of other Lexmark drivers - I'm going through and trying them all because one of them might work.  Also, I'm skipping the 16.04 LTS update because I tried it out and it was barely any different from 14.04 LTS but ran slightly slower.  I'm mostly just waiting for Unity 8 on an LTS release

Comment: Fair enough. If you can't get the printer to work on 14.04. I would try to get it to work on 16.04 using a live cd. That way you could find out if your printer works without upgrading, and if it does it would probably the preferable option instead of dual booting.

Comment: No; Wine cannot be used in a case like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is NO. A windows driver can not be "precompiled" for Linux.

However, a possible solution for you where you don't have to reboot the PC to use the printer is to consider using a Windows virtual machine that runs in Linux (check out VirtualBox.org).

Comment: Virtual machines aren't really an option for me - I tried but it took more time to boot the virtual machine and print than rebooting the computer (I currently have 1GB of RAM).